# Is it possible to validate on gridview in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a gridview with insert functionality and I'm trying to restrict the INSERT statement based on the number of rows that there are.  The problem with the way this is currently set up, is that when I enter a new row, the validation check works, but the row doesn't contain any data so an empty row is inserted into the gridview.

When I followed the code in the debugger, the local variables all came up as `""`, even though I had entered data in before pressing submit.

When I move the code block to AddNewCustomer without any validation, it works as it should.
I tried doing something like this:

(MGRchk is set to = datatable.rows.count)

```
private void BindData()
{
    string strQuery = "SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName AS FirstName, Person.LastName AS LastName, Person.Emergency# AS Emergency#, Person.Cell# AS Cell#, Person.Age AS Age, " +
                         "Person.ActivityCard AS ActivityCard, Person.CraftType AS CraftType, Person.Initials AS Initials, Person.Group# AS Group# " +
"FROM Person INNER JOIN " +
                         "TripSchedule ON Person.PersonID = TripSchedule.PersonID INNER JOIN Bus ON TripSchedule.BusID = Bus.BusID where TripSchedule.Date = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and " +
                         "TripSchedule.Time = '" + ddlTripTime.SelectedItem + "' and TripSchedule.TripType = '" + ddlTripType.SelectedItem + "' and Bus.Bus# = '" + ddlBus.SelectedItem + "' order by Person.Group#";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    TRIPTYPE = ddlTripType.SelectedItem.ToString();

    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    GridView1.DataBind();    
}

private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    int dtr = 0;
    dtr = dt.Rows.Count;
    MGRchk = dtr;

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Formats();
        PrintTable(dt);
        lblAct.Visible = false;
        lblAgee.Visible = false;
        lblBoats.Visible = false;
        lblCells.Visible = false;
        lblEmer.Visible = false;
        lblFirst.Visible = false;
        lblGroups.Visible = false;
        lblInit.Visible = false;
        lblLast.Visible = false;
        txtAct.Visible = false;
        ddlAgeR.Visible = false;
        ddlBoat1.Visible = false;
        txtCells.Visible = false;
        txtEmer.Visible = false;
        txtFirst.Visible = false;
        txtGroups.Visible = false;
        txtInit.Visible = false;
        txtLast.Visible = false;
        btnSubmitted.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lblAct.Visible = true;
        lblAgee.Visible = true;
        lblBoats.Visible = true;
        lblCells.Visible = true;
        lblEmer.Visible = true;
        lblFirst.Visible = true;
        lblGroups.Visible = true;
        lblInit.Visible = true;
        lblLast.Visible = true;
        txtAct.Visible = true;
        ddlAgeR.Visible = true;
        ddlBoat1.Visible = true;
        txtCells.Visible = true;
        txtEmer.Visible = true;
        txtFirst.Visible = true;
        txtGroups.Visible = true;
        txtInit.Visible = true;
        txtLast.Visible = true;
        btnSubmitted.Visible = true;
        txtAct.Text = "";
        txtCells.Text = "";
        txtEmer.Text = "";
        txtFirst.Text = "";
        txtGroups.Text = "";
        txtInit.Text = "";
        txtLast.Text = "";
    }

protected void AddNewCustomer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    BindData();

    switch(TRIP)
    {
        case "CANOE":
        if(MGRchk < 24)
        {
            ValidatedAdd(sender, e)
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError1.Text = error1;
        }    
    }
    //etc

protected void ValidatedAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nFirstName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
    string nLastName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
    string nEmergency = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmergency")).Text;
    string nCell = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCell")).Text;
    string nAge = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAge")).Text;
    string nActivityCard = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtActivityCard")).Text;
    string nInitials = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInitials")).Text;
    string nGroup = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGroup")).Text;
    string aboat = ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlBoat")).Text;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName, Emergency#, Cell#, Age, ActivityCard, CraftType, Initials, Group#) " +
      "values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Emergency, @Cell, @Age, @ActivityCard, @Boat, @Initials, @Group);"
      + "insert into TripSchedule(TripType, PersonID, Time, Date, BusID) values (@Type, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @Time, @Date, @Bus);" +
      "SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName AS FirstName, Person.LastName AS LastName, Person.Emergency# AS Emergency#, Person.Cell# AS Cell#, Person.Age AS Age, " +
      "Person.ActivityCard AS ActivityCard, Person.CraftType AS CraftType, Person.Initials AS Initials, Person.Group# AS Group# " +
      "FROM Person INNER JOIN " +
      "TripSchedule ON Person.PersonID = TripSchedule.PersonID INNER JOIN Bus on Bus.BusID = TripSchedule.BusID where TripSchedule.Date = @Date and " +
      "TripSchedule.Time = @Time and TripSchedule.TripType = @Type and Bus.BusID = @Bus order by Person.Group#;");



    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nFirstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nLastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emergency", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nEmergency;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cell", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nCell;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nAge;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityCard", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nActivityCard;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Initials", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nInitials;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nGroup;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", ddlTripTime.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ddlTripType.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Boat", aboat.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bus", ddlBus.SelectedItem.ToString());

    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you add a new customer, you bind the GridView *before* you do the insert. This re-binding will clear out your values every time.

Either remove that bind in `AddNewCustomer` (since you bind again in `ValidateAdd` anyway) or remove the bind in `ValidateAdd` and move the bind in `AddNewCustomer` to being *after* the insert.